# Update query to Reset counter when date column changes

Tags: mysql

```
column1   column_sec attempt      date    counter
1250       1250_A     1        16-06-2016    1     
1250       1250_B     1        16-06-2016    1  
1250       1250_C     1        16-06-2016    1  
1250       1250_A     2        16-06-2016    2  
1250       1250_B     2        16-06-2016    2  
1250       1250_C     2        16-06-2016    2  
1250       1250_A     3        06-06-2016    1  
1250       1250_B     3        06-06-2016    1  
1250       1250_C     3        06-06-2016    1  
1250       1250_A     4        06-06-2016    2  
1250       1250_B     4        06-06-2016    2  
1250       1250_C     4        06-06-2016    2
```

I want to write an update query when my date changes it will reset the counter column as shown above,
Can anyone help ?

So far i have tried this, But it increments counter by 1 till the end of the table.It did not help.

```
set @v1 := '', @v2 :='',@v3 :='', @num := 1;

select column1,column_sec,attempt,date,
   @num := if(@v1 := date,if(@v2 := column_sec,if(@v3 := column1,@num + 1,1),1),1) as counter
from table_name where date is not null
order by column1,column_sec,attempt;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you looked at existing examples of triggers? So far you are asking about things that can be learnt about in the manual and there's little point to just repeat the same things over again. However, I understand that when you are new to something, it's often easy to get confused. So perhaps you could elaborate on what your actual issue is that you want help with? That might make the learning process more effective for you.

Comment: updated my post.
Pls see what i have tried.

Comment: What you've added changes my understanding of the question completely, so thanks for the update. At first I thought you want a trigger that resets the `counter` column to 1 every time the `date` value on that row changes. Now it appears that you want something very different.

Comment: Column1 has 3 corresponding sectors in column_sec as shown and 3 attempts,
I want to check counts for same date for 3 sectors , it should reset everytime day changes or column1 changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
select column1,column_sec,attempt,date,
@num := if(@v1 != date OR @v2 != column_sec OR @v3 != column1, 1, @num + 1) AS counter,
@v1 := date,
@v2 := column_sec,
@v3 := column1
from table_name 
cross join (select @v1 := '', @v2 :='',@v3 :='', @num := 0) var_init_subquery
where date is not null
order by column1,column_sec,attempt;
```

The key is, that you have to check first, then assign the value of the current row. In the query you tried, you never assigned anything to the variables. When the next row (and the therefore the `select` clause) is processed, the variables hold the value of the previous row in the check, then the value of the current row is assigned to the variables.

Comment: Hi Tombom, It shows 1 for every record in counter column.

Comment: That's because every row changes in at least one of the columns date, column_sec or column1. Couldn't quite figure out your needs, just read it from the query you tried. Adjust the check in the `if()` function accordingly.

Comment: with little bit of changes in IF condition,
IT WORKED !!